# Salesforce sandbox access from Android Hybrid App

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce, hybrid

Is it possible to access test.salesforce.com from a Hybrid app generated with the Salesforce.com Mobile SDK for Android?

When using the iOS SDK, the login URL can be set via an application setting, however this does not seem possible within a Hybrid App on Android.

Do I need to modify the PhoneGap plugin SalesforceOAuthPlugin to do this?

I'm referring to the SDK available from https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this can't be done using javascript, if you're doin' this with mac, you have to change your app settings at (Settings | Your App | Custom Host) and replace login by test.

If you're doin' this on android, you have to edit the `DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL` attribute of the classe `com.salesforce.androidsdk.auth.OAuth2.java` to the test login URL (`https://test.salesforce.com`).

I was in this trouble since a week, and that's what I did and it works on my Hybrid App.

Comment: Thanks! I also found if I ran it on the right device I could change it via the server selection menu. It seems that menu is not visible on all devices.

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization